# Need to filter Google Analytics data

Tags: google-analytics

I'm really struggling to solve this problem.

In Google Analytics, we have been getting great data for a website. However, we rolled out kiosks a couple months ago. Each kiosk deletes cookies and refreshes the homepage every 5-15 minutes.

So, in the past 7 days, we are showing 94k new users...

All of them came from the same model of tablet, so it is easy to "segment" the data, but that doesn't help the front page (as it doesn't support segments, from what I can tell).

When segmenting, I get pretty good data, but it is still really limited.

From my understanding there is "no way to delete data" selectively from Analytics. That is really what I need to do, though.

We have the issue corrected, going forward. I set up a new Property for these devices, and we coded the site to recognize them and use the other property, and we have a non-reporting home screen, now, so we should be OK and get usable data going forward.

So, my question, what is the "best practice" for working around this garbage data so that we can perform unpolluted analysis?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an entirely new property for the kiosks, you could create Views for them within the existing property. That way, you don't need to manage multiple tracking IDs. (Just wanted to include that even though it wasn't exactly what you asked)

To work around the garbage, creating a segment would be the quickest solution– it should still work on the home page too (not sure why it wasn't for you without additional detail).

That being said, Google Analytics does have a feature now that can delete data. If you navigate to the **User Explorer** (under Audience) and click into one of the Client IDs, you'll see a **"Delete User" button** on the left side. This feature was introduced to comply with GDPR.

If you use your segments that identify these kiosks, you can then use the User Explorer report with the segmented data to begin deleting them. That being said, if the number of new users you're seeing is knocking at the door of 100k this may not be a feasible solution for you. Maybe you can bulk delete users with the API or something?

Down the road, you may consider altering the tracking code when these kiosks view the website so that when they refresh it doesn't send a pageview, but when a user is actually using it then it does (maybe a query string on the refresh trigger?). Just food for thought- best of luck!